# Creating array using structure

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I recently started learning c++ to change my career.

I understood some basic pointer logic and I wanted make an array using the structure.

So basically, here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
struct arr{
private:
    int size;
    int *elements;
public:
    void createarray(int start, int end);
    void printa();
};
void arr::createarray(int start, int end){
size=end-start;
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
    *(elements+i)=start+i;
}
}

void arr::printa(){
    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        cout << *(elements+i) << endl;
    }
}
```

so basically, my logic was that:
If I can make a pointer variable that stores the random memory address of the c++ and perform increment pointer arithmetic, then I can basically create my own array notation using the structure or class.

But the above code gives me an error. So, I am guessing it's because performing arithmetic to uninitialized pointer is invalid in c. Am I correct? Or is there something else that I am missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: While it's good learning about pointers, and how to use them to create dynamic "arrays", once you learned that lesson you can throw it all aways because whenever you think "dynamic array" when programming in C++ your next through should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: There is no dynamic array created in any of this. something like `new int[size];` will have to be in there sooner or later, as will fixing the conditional limit of your for-loop to be strictly-less-than `size`. As written now, this is a recipe for *undefined behavior*, assuming an instance of `arr` is ever actually created (no posted code does that either). Finally, "performing arithmetic with an uninitialized pointer..." doing *anything*, be it pointer arithmetic, or even simple evaluation, with *indeterminate* variable content constitutes *undefined behavior* of the most basic form.

Comment: So I found that by declaring *p and dereferencing is not even allowed. I initially thought that pointer declaration and dereferencing will automatically assign that pointer some random address... I guess this was a stupid question.

Comment: Don't try to write your own classes until to got the grasp on class basics. The C++ idiom is to write constructors and destructors. It ties initialization with object defintion. Its one of C++'s major strengths.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating any memory for your dynamic array. Really, it should look something like this:

```
struct arr {
private:
    int size;
    int *elems;

public:
    // createarray should be a constructor
    arr(int start, int end) {
        size = end - start + 1;
        elems = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            elems[i] = start + i;
    }

    // clean up memory
    ~arr() {
        // make sure to include the '[]'
        delete[] elems;
    }

    // print array
    void printa() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            std::cout << elems[i] << "\n";
    }
};
```

Of course, ideally you'd use a `std::vector` rather than rolling your own dynamic array.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't know it was possible. So you need to allocate memory!! After seeing the code, now I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
void arr::createarray(int start, int end){
    size=end-start;
    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        *(elements+i)=start+i;
}
```

First off, why not put it in a `constructor` instead? It's a function with the same name as the struct, and doesn't have a return type (not even void). It's called whenever a struct of that type is instantiated.

Secondly, arrays and pointers are pretty much interchangable in C.
`*(elements+i)` can also be written as `elements[i]`.

---

Your problem is that you never allocate memory for `elements`. You're doing arithmetic and assignment to an uninitialized pointer, which is *undefined behaviour*. You should use the `new` keyword and give it a size.

```
elements = new int[size];
```

When you `new` something, you must also `delete` it when you're done. Otherwise you'll leak memory.
A reasonable place to do this is in the destructor (same as constructor, prefixed with `~`, but is called when the instance of the struct dies).

But you don't have to concern yourself with this headache. The STL has a container that does what you want. `std::vector`

Comment: Arrays and pointers aren't as interchangeable as many think. One *decays* into the other under certain conditions, but that's where it pretty much ends.